# How to move on premises file to a different directory using azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to move on premises file to a different directory after they are done getting copied over to azure blob storage, using azure data factory. Does anybody have an idea on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you using `Azure Trigger Function` to implement your requirements.

Step 1:
You could create an [Azure Function Blob Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function) to monitor your blob account.

Step 2:
Whenever a blob file enters a blob storage , the code in the trigger will be executed. You could get the blob full name and push it as message into e.g. `Azure Queue Storage`.

Step 3:
Then you create an on premise service (or application or script) which runs continuously to monitor the queue storage.If a message enters, then get the file name and move it to another folder.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve using Azure Data Factory -

Have an event-based triggers that you can create in your Data Factory(V2) pipeline, this would basically trigger pipelines based on events.
From the documentation:

> As soon as the file arrives in your storage location and the
>   corresponding blob is created, this event triggers and runs your Data
>   Factory pipeline. You can create a trigger that responds to a blob
>   creation event, a blob deletion event, or both events, in your Data
>   Factory pipelines.

Link - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger). & [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/event-trigger-based-scheduling-in-azure-data-factory/)

Once this is done your next step would be copy activity for Azure Data Factory to copy data from and to file system. Note - you need to set up a Self-hosted Integration Runtime for copy activity to work on file system ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime))

Link - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system).

Comment: Someone just downvoted, could you please care to explain the reason behind?